# How to plot a table with multiple columns as a box plot

Tags: r, rstudio, ggplot2

[image]I am trying to plot a box plot with the Trinucleotide as the x axis (so 64 trinucleotides on the x axis) and the frequency of each trinucleotide in each of 6 samples then color code the plot according to the sample. This is a snippet of the table and the code I have so far as well as the type of graph I want.

```
ibrary(tidyverse)
library(readxl)

marte <- read_xlsx("TrinucleotideFrequency06182021.xlsx")
marte <- gather (marte, "xzl.mmu.C57.testis.wt.adult.40S_crosslink.rep1+rept1.RPF.trimmed.gz.x_rRNA.x_hairpin.mm10v1.unique.+jxn.bed13.40S.sense.hybrid.utr3.1up.5end.PNLDC1.rep1.bed6", "xzl.mmu.C57.testis.wt.adult.40S_crosslink.rep2+rept2.RPF.R1.trimmed.gz.x_rRNA.x_hairpin.mm10v1.unique.+jxn.bed13.40S.sense.hybrid.utr3.1up.5end.PNLDC1.rep1.bed6", "xzl.mmu.C57.testis.wt.adult.40S_crosslink.rep3+rept3.RPF.R1.trimmed.gz.x_rRNA.x_hairpin.mm10v1.unique.+jxn.bed13.40S.sense.hybrid.utr3.1up.5end.PNLDC1.rep1.bed6", "xzl.mmu.C57.testis.wt.adult.80S_crosslink.rep1+rept1.RPF.trimmed.gz.x_rRNA.x_hairpin.mm10v1.unique.+jxn.bed13.RPF.sense.hybrid.utr3.1up.5end.PNLDC1.rep1.bed6", "xzl.mmu.C57.testis.wt.adult.80S_crosslink.rep2+rept2.RPF.R1.trimmed.gz.x_rRNA.x_hairpin.mm10v1.unique.+jxn.bed13.RPF.sense.hybrid.utr3.1up.5end.PNLDC1.rep1.bed6", "xzl.mmu.C57.testis.wt.adult.80S_crosslink.rep3+rept3.RPF.R1.trimmed.gz.x_rRNA.x_hairpin.mm10v1.unique.+jxn.bed13.RPF.sense.hybrid.utr3.1up.5end.PNLDC1.rep1.bed6",key="gene", value="value")
marte$gene <- as.factor(marte$Trinucleotide)  
marte$group <- as.factor(marte$gene)

ggplot(marte, aes(x = gene, y = value, color = group)) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

head (marte) produces the output below and underneath is a part of the table I am using to generate the plot with the first column as the trinucleotide and the other 6 as each gene respectively.

```
 Trinucleotide gene   value group
  <chr>         <fct>  <dbl> <fct>
1 AAA           AAA   0.0214 AAA  
2 TAG           TAG   0.0199 TAG  
3 AGC           AGC   0.0132 AGC  
4 TGT           TGT   0.0338 TGT  
5 GAT           GAT   0.0130 GAT  
6 CAC           CAC   0.0112 CAC
```

```
AAA 0.021383202 0.016654469 0.022484448 0.025311535 0.025495724 0.02017925
TAG 0.019927531 0.018790672 0.015649845 0.02230479  0.019363723 0.02017925
AGC 0.013209711 0.016891825 0.014520044 0.014302046 0.014804269 0.012904701
TGT 0.033757832 0.034990209 0.031899462 0.034446096 0.034475058 0.031047513
GAT 0.013006661 0.007615167 0.009163947 0.010540757 0.008234933 0.012000828
CAC 0.011210666 0.015012758 0.01241387  0.011478221 0.011045046 0.013579884
GGG 0.012712095 0.011927132 0.013222864 0.011558249 0.014292494 0.014647108
CGA 0.00230219  0.000969203 0.001325076 0.002034983 0.001656292 0.002036438
TCG 0.004169681 0.007377811 0.005649008 0.005133189 0.006057561 0.006131094
ACA 0.011259284 0.013825979 0.010656401 0.009900537 0.010617015 0.009670358
```

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. I'm confused about what you're asking, the graph you show is not what you want? If not can you please clarify what you would like to obtain differently?

Comment: I have an excel sheet with a column that contains trinucleotides and 6 other columns containing the frequency of each trinucleotide in 6 different genes(there are 64 trinucleotides in total). I would like to plot the data in a box plot similar to the one above with the trinucleotide as the x axis and frequency as y axis wit each box representing a gene

Comment: Trinucleotide Gene 1 Gene 2. Gene 3. Gene 4. Gene 5. Gene 6                                                    AAG                 0.2.      0.6         0.8.        0.9.       0.8.          0.3                                             ACG                 0.09.    0.09.   0.87.        0.45.      0.22.        0.05                                           GGC                 0.1.      0.7.        0.9         0.98.       0.8          0.92                                          TCA                 0.9        0.65      0.5          0.2         0.54        0.09

Comment: Unfortunately I can't attach the table as a comment @Erwan

Comment: I managed to post the table on r community if you have a moment to check https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-to-plot-a-table-with-multiple-columns-as-a-box-plot/107938

Comment: Ok that's a bit clearer but a screenshot is not very helpful, I can't use it to test what happens, and the columns names are not even visible. What is the problem exactly: do you obtain the table `marte` in the right format, with columns `gene`, `value` and `group`? Maybe you can edit the question to add a copy-paste result of `head(marte)`. Otherwise, if the problem is that you don't obtain exactly the plot that you want, can you please show the plot that you obtain? The code looks correct to me, but without any data I can't debug anything.

Comment: @Erwan I just did that!

Comment: Ok, as far as I understand the group column is incorrect: it's supposed to contain which of the 6 samples the row belongs to, but instead it's just the trinucleotide (which is also copied in the gene column). So the question is: where can you obtain the sample information in your data? Given the format of your data I assume that it's encoded in the columns names somehow. How many columns do you have in the file at the beginning? If it's not too many can you copy-paste the full columns names? Do you know which columns correspond to which sample?

Comment: I just realized something: do you have one column for each sample or more than one column? Because if you have only one column for each sample and only one row for each trinuclueotide, then it means that you have a single value for every pair (trinucleotide+sample) and in this case it wouldn't make sense to use boxplots.

Comment: I have one column for each sample but I wanted to pair 80s and 40s to have 2 samples for each trinucleotide. These are the names of the 6 columns:

Comment: xzl.mmu.C57.testis.wt.adult.40S_crosslink.rep1+rept1.RPF.trimmed.gz.x_rRNA.x_hairpin.mm10v1.unique.+jxn.bed13.40S.sense.hybrid.utr3.1up.5end.PNLDC1.rep1.bed6 xzl.mmu.C57.testis.wt.adult.40S_crosslink.rep2+rept2.RPF.R1.trimmed.gz.x_rRNA.x_hairpin.mm10v1.unique.+jxn.bed13.40S.sense.hybrid.utr3.1up.5end.PNLDC1.rep1.bed6 xzl.mmu.C57.testis.wt.adult.40S_crosslink.rep3+rept3.RPF.R1.trimmed.gz.x_rRNA.x_hairpin.mm10v1.unique.+jxn.bed13.40S.sense.hybrid.utr3.1up.5end.PNLDC1.rep1.bed6

Comment: xzl.mmu.C57.testis.wt.adult.80S_crosslink.rep1+rept1.RPF.trimmed.gz.x_rRNA.x_hairpin.mm10v1.unique.+jxn.bed13.RPF.sense.hybrid.utr3.1up.5end.PNLDC1.rep1.bed6 xzl.mmu.C57.testis.wt.adult.80S_crosslink.rep2+rept2.RPF.R1.trimmed.gz.x_rRNA.x_hairpin.mm10v1.unique.+jxn.bed13.RPF.sense.hybrid.utr3.1up.5end.PNLDC1.rep1.bed6 xzl.mmu.C57.testis.wt.adult.80S_crosslink.rep3+rept3.RPF.R1.trimmed.gz.x_rRNA.x_hairpin.mm10v1.unique.+jxn.bed13.RPF.sense.hybrid.utr3.1up.5end.PNLDC1.rep1.bed6

Comment: @Erwan So my vision was to have 40s rept1+rep1 with 80s rep 1, 40s rep2 and  80s rep2 then 40s rep3 and 80s rep3

Answer (score 0):

Based on the explanations in the comments, what you need is to format the data so that every sample has the right 'group' label. Since there are only 6 columns I would just do it manually like below.

```
marte <- read_xlsx("TrinucleotideFrequency06182021.xlsx")

a40 <- data.frame(gene=marte$Trinucleotide,value=marte[,2])
b40 <- data.frame(gene=marte$Trinucleotide,value=marte[,3])
c40 <- data.frame(gene=marte$Trinucleotide,value=marte[,4])
a80 <- data.frame(gene=marte$Trinucleotide,value=marte[,5])
b80 <- data.frame(gene=marte$Trinucleotide,value=marte[,6])
c80 <- data.frame(gene=marte$Trinucleotide,value=marte[,7])

# these should not be necessary:
colnames(a40) <- c('gene','value')
colnames(b40) <- c('gene','value')
colnames(c40) <- c('gene','value')
colnames(a80) <- c('gene','value')
colnames(b80) <- c('gene','value')
colnames(c80) <- c('gene','value')

gp1 <- rbind(a40,b40,c40)
gp1$group <- rep('40s',nrow(gp1))
gp2 <- rbind(a80,b80,c80)
gp2$group <- rep('80s',nrow(gp2))

ggplot(marte, aes(x = gene, y = value, color = group)) +geom_boxplot()+ theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))+coord_flip()
```

[image: Plot]

Explanation: for each sample a dataframe which contains only the values coming from the three columns of this sample. The three parts are concatenated by rows (`rbind`) with the columns `gene` and `value`, then the column `group` is added containing the id of the group (sample) in every row.

For the record, doing boxplots with only two values is not great, a boxplot is supposed to show the distribution of a set of values. I would suggest simple barplots instead, with the two values shown as different bars.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126773/discussion-on-answer-by-erwan-how-to-plot-a-table-with-multiple-columns-as-a-box).